# Juniper EX2500 - default gateway enabled but down

Tags: juniper, trunk

I'm trying to configure an EX2500 (first time with a Juniper), and I configured a trunk on our Cisco device, and then tagged the port on the EX2500. The link between the two comes up fine. However, I am unable to ping the primary IP address I set on the ex2500. Looking at `sh ip information` on the EX2500, I get:

```
    Interface information:

   1: 192.168.28.230       255.255.255.192     192.168.28.192,vlan216, up

Default gateway information:
  192.168.28.193, enabled,  down

Current IP forwarding settings: OFF, noicmprd enabled
```

Is there a reason why the gateway would be enabled but listed as down?

My configuration:

```
spanning-tree mode pvrst

interface ip 1
 ipvlan 216
 ip address  192.168.28.230 255.255.255.192
 enable
!
interface ip 1
ip gateway address 192.168.28.193
ip gateway enable
```

I created the VLAN, and the port is assigned to it.

The VLAN is allowed on the Cisco device trunk as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: could you please un-obscure the IP addresses - since the subnet masks are all greater than /24, replace the first 2 octets with 192.168 or 10.0 - but don't mangle the last 2

and obviously, the first 2 octets of all of them **are** identical, right?

Comment: I modified the ip's so you can see better.

Comment: Can you ping 192.168.28.193 from Juniper?

Comment: @NetworkNinja Were you ever able to get additional information?  I'm prepping a test-bed today to give you some baseline configs. From here, it looks like your Cisco gear has IP address 192.168.28.230/26 on VLAN 216, while your Juniper gear has IP address 192.168.28.193/26 on VLAN 216. You also mentioned that you had them connected through a trunk, is that correct?